# KernelRestarter: restart failed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Jupyter notebook was installed with conda.

When notebook file is run, I have this "KernelRestarter: restart failed" error.
All error messages are as follows.

```
KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/itc/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/itc/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/itc/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/home/itc/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/home/itc/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/home/itc/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/home/itc/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 18, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.interactiveshell import TerminalInteractiveShell
  File "/home/itc/anaconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 20, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit.shortcuts import create_prompt_application, create_eventloop, create_prompt_layout, create_output
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_prompt_application'
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]

---

Looking at the same problem as me. The `ipykernel` of my virtual environment cannot be started because of the wrong version of the component.

now fixed it.

```
pip3 install -U ipykernel
```

[image]